# Catching return values from goroutines

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

The below code gives compilation error saying 'unexpected go':

```
x := go doSomething(arg)

func doSomething(arg int) int{
    ...
    return my_int_value
}
```

I know, I can fetch the return value if I call the function normally i.e. without using goroutine or I can use channels etc.

My question is why is it not possible to fetch a return value like this from a goroutine.

Comment: you could use a channel to return it

Comment: why does it allow having a return value for a goroutine

Comment: @rogerdpack that requires changing api of whatever function you are using. so you might need a wrapper function if it's not your own

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The strict answer is that you *can* do that. It's just probably not a good idea. Here's code that would do that:

```
var x int
go func() {
    x = doSomething()
}()
```

This will spawn off a new goroutine which will calculate `doSomething()` and then assign the result to `x`. The problem is: how are you going to use `x` from the original goroutine? You probably want to make sure the spawned goroutine is done with it so that you don't have a race condition. But if you want to do that, you'll need a way to communicate with the goroutine, and if you've got a way to do that, why not just use it to send the value back?

Comment: You can add a WaitGroup to make sure you've finished and wait for it. But as you said, it's just not the way to do it, a channel is.

Comment: This is not `return`, this is `assign`ment

Comment: @NidhinDavid well technically, assignment is how returning is implemented in assembly...

Answer (score 176):

#### Why is it not possible to fetch a return value from a goroutine assigning it to a variable?

Run goroutine (asynchronously) and fetch return value from function  are essentially contradictory actions. When you say `go` you mean "do it asynchronously" or even simpler: "Go on! Don't wait for the function execution be finished". But when you assign function return value to a variable you are expecting to have this value within the variable. So when you do that `x := go doSomething(arg)` you are saying: "Go on, don't wait for the function! Wait-wait-wait! I need a returned value be accessible in `x` var right in the next line below!"

#### Channels

The most natural way to fetch a value from a goroutine is channels. Channels are the pipes that connect concurrent goroutines. You can send values into channels from one goroutine and receive those values into another goroutine or in a synchronous function. You could easily obtain a value from a goroutine not breaking concurrency using `select`:

```
func main() {

    c1 := make(chan string)
    c2 := make(chan string)

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
        c1 <- "one"
    }()
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
        c2 <- "two"
    }()

    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        // Await both of these values
        // simultaneously, printing each one as it arrives.
        select {
        case msg1 := <-c1:
            fmt.Println("received", msg1)
        case msg2 := <-c2:
            fmt.Println("received", msg2)
        } 
    }
}
```

*The example is taken from Go By Example*

#### CSP & message-passing

Go is largerly based on [CSP theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes). The naive description from above could be precisely outlined in terms of CSP (although I believe it is out of scope of the question). I strongly recommend to familiarize yourself with CSP theory at least because it is RAD. These short quotations give a direction of thinking:

> As its name suggests, CSP allows the description of systems in terms of component processes that **operate independently**, and interact with each other solely through **message-passing communication**.
>
> In computer science, message passing sends a message to a process and relies on the process and the supporting infrastructure to select and invoke the actual code to run. Message passing differs from conventional programming where a process, subroutine, or function is directly invoked by name.

Answer (score 9):

The idea of the `go` keyword is that you run the doSomething function asynchronously, and continue the current goroutine without waiting for the result, kind of like executing a command in a Bash shell with an '&' after it. If you want to do

```
x := doSomething(arg)
// Now do something with x
```

then you need the current goroutine to block until doSomething finishes. So why not just call doSomething *in* the current goroutine? There are other options (like, doSomething could post a result to a channel, which the current goroutine receives values from) but simply calling doSomething and assigning the result to a variable is obviously simpler.

Answer (score 6):

It's a design choice by Go creators. There's a whole lot of abstractions/APIs to represent the value of async I/O operations - `promise`, `future`, `async/await`, `callback`, `observable`, etc. These abstractions/APIs are inherently tied to the unit of scheduling - **coroutines** - and these abstractions/APIs dictate how coroutines (or more precisely the return value of async I/O represented by them) can be *composed*.

Go chose message passing (aka *channels*) as the abstraction/API to represent the return value of async I/O operations. And of course, goroutines and channels give you a composable tool to implement async I/O operations.

Answer (score 6):

Why not use a channel to write into?

```
chanRes := make(chan int, 1)
go doSomething(arg, chanRes)
//blocks here or you can use some other sync mechanism (do something else) and wait
x := <- chanRes
func doSomething(arg int, out chan<- int){
    ...
    out <- my_int_value
}
```

Comment: I actually liked this answer. It is not complicated to understand