# How get result of running the goroutine?

Tags: go

In other languages, I can run several tasks in concurrently and get the result of each in corresponding variable.

For example in JS:

```
getApi1()
 .then( res => console.debug("Result 1: ", res) )

getApi2()
 .then( res => console.debug("Result 2: ", res) )

getApi3()
 .then( res => console.debug("Result 3: ", res) )
```

And I know exactly in which variable the result of the execution of which function.

The same is in Python asyncio:

```
task1 = asyncio.create_task(getApi1)
task2 = asyncio.create_task(getApi2)
result1 = await task1
result2 = await task2
```

I'm new in Go lang. All guides say to use channels with goroutines.

But I don't understand, when I read from the channel, how to be sure which message matches which result?

```
resultsChan := make(chan map)

go getApi1(resultsChan)
go getApi2(resultsChan)
go getApi3(resultsChan)

for {
 result, ok := <- resultsChan

 if ok == false {
  break
 
 } else {

  // HERE
  fmt.Println(result)  // How to understand which message the result of what API request?
 
 }

}
```

Comment: `make(chan map)` wouldn't compile. Please post a MWE. To answer your question, if you care about where the result comes from, you should use an appropriate channel element type (e.g. `type Result struct { api string }`).

Comment: @jub0bs, any way, how to match results to my API calls?

Comment: goroutines don't return *results:* they run until they return, but their return type is always "returns nothing at all". So there is no result to *get*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catching return values from goroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945069/catching-return-values-from-goroutines)

Comment: What is the element type of `resultsChan`? If it's a struct, could you not simply add a field to it that would indicate where the result comes from?

Answer (score 2):

> How to understand which message the result of what API request?

If the same channel is to communicate the results from all your `getApiN` functions to `main` and you want to programmatically determine where each result came from, you can simply add a dedicated field to your channel element type. Below, I've declared a custom struct type named `Result` with a field named `orig` for precisely that purpose.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Origin int

const (
    Unknown Origin = iota
    API1
    API2
    API3
)

type Result struct {
    orig Origin
    data string
}

func getApi1(c chan Result) {
    res := Result{
        orig: API1,
        data: "some value",
    }
    c <- res
}

func getApi2(c chan Result) {
    res := Result{
        orig: API2,
        data: "some value",
    }
    c <- res
}

func getApi3(c chan Result) {
    res := Result{
        orig: API3,
        data: "some value",
    }
    c <- res
}

func main() {
    results := make(chan Result, 3)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(3)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        getApi1(results)
    }()
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        getApi2(results)
    }()
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        getApi3(results)
    }()
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(results)
    }()
    for res := range results {
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", res)
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ziQK16pY7fd))

Possible output (the order of results isn't deterministic):

```
main.Result{orig:1, data:"some value"}
main.Result{orig:2, data:"some value"}
main.Result{orig:3, data:"some value"}
```

---

At any rate, I would not follow [wic's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67821988/2541573); your problem is simply not a good use case for reflection. [As Rob Pike puts it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAAkCSZUG1c&t=15m23s),

> Reflection is never clear. Another thing you see on Stack Overflow a lot is people trying to use `reflect` and wondering why it doesn't work. It doesn't work because it's not for you... Very, very few people should be playing with reflection. It's a very powerful but very difficult-to-use feature. [...]

Comment: @VonC Not sure I understand; nowhere am I incrementing a counter.

Comment: Right, I read your answer too fast. I thought incrementing an ID would be needed in case of a single channel to identify each result.

Comment: @VonC No problem. Thanks about the upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`chebyrash/promise`](https://github.com/chebyrash/promise) for that (which uses channel behind the scene)

```golang
var p1 = promise.Resolve(123)
var p2 = promise.Resolve("Hello, World")
var p3 = promise.Resolve([]string{"one", "two", "three"})

results, _ := promise.All(p1, p2, p3).Await()
fmt.Println(results)
// [123 Hello, World [one two three]]
```

As explained in "[Catching return values from goroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57335058/6309)":

> It is a design choice by Go creators.
> There's a whole lot of abstractions/APIs to represent the value of async I/O operations - `promise`, [`future`](http://www.golangpatterns.info/concurrency/futures), `async/await`, `callback`, `observable`, etc

The project I mention above is an example of composition which allows to get "promises".

---

To achieve the same natively, you would need one channel per expected result.
See as an example "[Use Go Channels as Promises and Async/Await](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/use-go-channels-as-promises-and-async-await-ee62d93078ec)" (from [**Minh-Phuc Tran**](https://twitter.com/phuctm97)), and this [playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/5JomJTkFUxb):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func longRunningTask() <-chan int32 {
    r := make(chan int32)

    go func() {
        defer close(r)
        
        // Simulate a workload.
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
        r <- rand.Int31n(100)
    }()

    return r
}

func main() {
    aCh, bCh, cCh := longRunningTask(), longRunningTask(), longRunningTask()
    a, b, c := <-aCh, <-bCh, <-cCh
    
    fmt.Println(a, b, c)
}
```

Interesting comments from the OP:

> What if I need run 500 API calls concurrently? Should I make 500 channels?

See "[Max number of goroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8509152/6309)": 500 goroutines (and their channels) is nothing

> What if I don't know in advance count of API calls? For example, I get params and get API calls over it array unknown length?

Then, assuming we are talking about a large number of calls, you can use a [worker pool](https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools), as in this more [sophisticated example](https://www.prakharsrivastav.com/posts/golang-concurrent-worker-pool/).
You would need to return a result tagged with a job id in order to match it with the variable which expect a specific result.

Comment: This is interesting, thanks. But I want to know how to do it natively.

Comment: @morfair Sure. I have edited the answer to illustrate a (simple) native implementation.

Comment: No, no, no... What if I need run 500 API calls concurrently? Should I make 500 channels?
What if I don't know in advance count of API calls? For example, I get params and get API calls over it array unknown length?

Comment: @morfair 1/ They are cheap, so you can have a lot of them. 2/ It depends on the nature of your program: you can have for example a pool of channels in order to mange *large* batch of calls (and by large, I mean way bigger than 500).

Comment: And again, how to match results from channels pool?..

Comment: @morfair you don't have to match results: each variable in a given batch is assigned *one* channel which will bring back its assigned result.

Answer (score 0):

An other way to do is to use goroutine rather than channels. It depends whether you want to have some synchronization on the callbacks or not. This:

```
getApi1()
 .then( res => console.debug("Result 1: ", res))

getApi2()
 .then( res => console.debug("Result 2: ", res) )

getApi3()
 .then( res => console.debug("Result 3: ", res) )
```

Would become

```
go func(){
    res := getApi1()
    fmt.Println("Result 1: ", res)
}
go func(){
    res := getApi2()
    fmt.Println("Result 2: ", res)
}
go func(){
    res := getApi3()
    fmt.Println("Result 3: ", res)
}
```

Comment: I would like both.
First, I should get all results and hanle its together.
Secont, I must be able to process separately.

Answer (score -1):

The best practice is to have a channel for each goroutine and make a `select` statement containing all channels, but it sounds like much-repeated code. So, you need to do that but with a generic code, Go have a powerful package called `reflection`. If you are new to Go, I recommend you to learn `reflection`. So, you can apply this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19992525/10446155 and the code looks like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func getApi1(c chan string) {
    c <- "value from Api1"
}

func getApi2(c chan string) {
    c <- "value from Api2"
}

func getApi3(c chan string) {
    c <- "value from Api3"
}

// Array with all channels
var responses []chan string

func init() {
    responses = make([]chan string, 3)
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        responses[i] = make(chan string)
    }
}

func main() {
    // Call each ApiFunction with different channel
    go getApi1(responses[0])
    go getApi2(responses[1])
    go getApi3(responses[2])

    // Generic select statement with reflection
    cases := make([]reflect.SelectCase, len(responses))
    for i, ch := range responses {
        cases[i] = reflect.SelectCase{
            Dir:  reflect.SelectRecv,
            Chan: reflect.ValueOf(ch),
        }
    }

    count := len(cases)
    for {
        chosen, value, ok := reflect.Select(cases)
        if !ok {
            panic(fmt.Sprintf("channel at index %d is closed", chosen))
        }
        fmt.Printf("getApi%d returns: %s\n", chosen+1, value.String())
        // Count each select, and break if all are made. If you don't 
        // do this, then your code enter in a deadlock condition
        count -= 1
        if count == 0 {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

> Note: I suppose all ApiFunctionrs returns a `string`

Comment: Yes, I suggested a channel per variable,... It did not go well.

Comment: I'm wary of approaches that use reflection and/or `init` for something so common...